# Returning a Date for the first of the month

Tags: macos, swiftui

I have an issue with a macOS Date() that is driving me nuts.

I simply want to change the Date() to be the first of the same month and year.  Seems trivial...

```
import Foundation
extension Date {

func firstOfMonth() -> Date {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        return calendar.date(bySetting: .day , value: 1, of: self) ?? Date()
    }

}
```

When I call the function it gives me the first of the next month.

I've tried setting the calendar to UTC, just in case, and still the same problem

Here is what I am seeing when using the function

[image: example]

I am assuming this is some mental block I am having here or simply signs of approaching senility.  Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try something like this, to return the first of the same month and year.

```
extension Date {
    
    func firstOfMonth() -> Date {
        var calendar = Calendar.current
        calendar.timeZone = .gmt
        let compo = calendar.dateComponents([.month, .year], from: self)
        if let newDate = DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: compo.year, month: compo.month, day: 1).date {
            return newDate
        } else {
            return Date()
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: That works fine.  I would love to know why my origional (and Mojtaba's versions) don't work.

Comment: I guess that by using `DateComponents(calendar: calendar, year: compo.year, month: compo.month, day: 1).date`
 it is forcing the date to be exactly as described, the same `year` and the same `month`.
 Whereas `calendar.date(bySetting: .day , value: 1, of: self)` as described in the code docs, the exact behavior of this method is implementation-defined, and so 
 `The algorithm will try to produce a result which is in the next-larger component to the one given ...`

Comment: Ah the penny drops...  I read that when trying to resolve it myself.  My brain didn't correlate 'next-larger component' with month.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thats because of the calendar settings.

You can get the 1st of the current month by dropping the day component like:

```
func logical1st() -> Date {
    cal.date(from: cal.dateComponents([.year, .month], from: cal.startOfDay(for: self)))!
}

print(date.logical1st())
```

It prints `2023-09-30 20:30:00 +0000` in **my** calendar settings. Because it is the correct time in the GMT timezone when it is `2023-10-01` here in my timezone.

So I can make it `2023-10-01` by passing a `GMT` calendar like:

```
var gmtCal = Calendar.current
gmtCal.timeZone = .gmt

print(date.logical1st(calendar: gmtCal))
```

Now it prints `2023-10-01 00:00:00 +0000` as expected

<sub>⚠️ Important note! Calendar is far more complicated than it seems and I can not guarantee the above solution or any other! You should have a good test coverage for this.</sub>

Comment: Mojtaba, thanks for the reply.  I actually tried this approach and I still had exactly the same problem.  No mater what date I start with, even if it is in the middle of the month I still get the first of the next month.